# D&D 5e - Monks' Unarmed Strike

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

I've been trying to find out whether I add the proficiency bonus to my monk's unarmed strike attack, ie 1d4 + DEX + PROFICIENCY vs 1d4 + DEX. I've found some sources that say yes but most only seem to add the ability modifier. Any sources you could reference along with your answer would be a big help, thanks,

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: We've marked your question as a dupe because it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. (If it doesn't answer your question for you, you should edit this question to clarify the difference. Feel free to ask if anything is confusing.)

Answer (score 6):

When making your attack, there are two rolls to consider, the attack roll (which determines if you hit) and the damage roll (which determines how much damage you do).

The attack roll is a d20 + your ability modifier + your proficiency
 bonus. You only add your proficiency bonus if you are proficient with the attack, and all characters are proficient with unarmed strikes. Thus, you would roll d20+DEX+PROF to see if you hit.

The damage roll is a d4+DEX, as the martial arts ability of the monk states

> You can use Dexterity instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of your unarmed strikes and monk weapons.
>   You can roll a d4 in place of the normal damage of your unarmed strike or monk weapon. This die changes as you gain monk levels, as shown in the Martial Arts column of the Monk table.

You do not, in general, add proficiency bonuses to damage rolls, only attack rolls.

I recommend reading through the Combat section of the Basic Rules (available for free online).